# Using get_queryset() in ViewSets, can't access the Detail Views. Error: Cannot use None as a query value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I do a DELETE request to `127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/10/`, I get the error that Cannot use None as a query value.

**views.py**

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        p1 = self.request.query_params.get('parameter')    
        queryset = Task.objects.nearby(p1)    
        return queryset

    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
task_list = views.TaskViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
task_detail = views.TaskViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^tasks/$', task_list, name='task-list'),
    url(r'^tasks/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', task_detail, name='task-detail'),
]
```

Everything works fine for list e.g. all requests to `127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/`. However, none of the request work for the detail views. I'm assuming it's something to do with the `get_queryset()`.

Comment: What's Task.objects.nearby(p1) ?

Comment: It sorts results closest to a point. It returns a list of objects, instead of using `.objects.all()` or `.objects.filter()`

Comment: Then it won't work as the get_queryset obviously should return a queryset and not a list.

Comment: @Linovia it works for the list set, but fails only on detail. (P.S. It does return a set, I called it list by mistake)

Comment: set still not a queryset and yes it will work on list provided you don't filter, nor paginate nor....

Comment: @Linovia thanks, so for my needs, I have to use function based views and write custom views for what I need done.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL captures the value as the `pk` parameter, but you are trying to get `parameter` in your `get_queryset` method.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm guessing I should just write function based views? They seem to be more effective

Comment: Er, no, I can't imagine how you got that from what I wrote. You just need to use the right name for the parameter, ie `pk`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I need. This parameters is used to sort objects when I do a GET request to `127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/?parameter=5` in the list view to sort results on distance and show all objects, but it just happens that this class based view also has the same `get_queryset()` for the detail view. This is why I thought it's impossible. If I include `pk`, then the list view will complain that there is no `pk` parameter